# Video frame capture: I-frame vs P-frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, python, video-encoding, video-capture

I'm trying to capture various frames within a x264-encoded video files into `png` files (in `python`), and then compare the quality of them:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename);
//get frame_number for saving, and save the frame
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frame_no);
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite(dir_path+'uniform_frame_'+str(frame_no)+".png", frame);
```

Now I was wondering if I fetch an **I-Frame**, does it mean that it has a higher quality than other frames, e.g. **P-frames** and **B-Frames**? (inherently, keyframes are not compressed, so they must have higher quality and less noise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All frames within an encoded video stream are compressed; I-frame simply indicates that the picture can be reconstructed without reference to other coded pictures.

Now, since I-frames are typically used as references for other pictures, a smart encoder goes easy on the quantization, so they typically are of greater quality. P-frames have more quantization applied and B-frames even more.

Comment: Thanks. So the saved frame files usually have higher qualities.

Comment: @TinaJ Usually, yes, unless while encoding, somebody played with the settings. I-frames are more costly to encode than P- or B-frames, so there is a tradeoff to be made. See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings#ipratio

Comment: @slhck btw another quick question: what is the intervals between I-frames? I noticed 1 every FPS in the videos I saw (e.g. 1 per 30 frames). Is it always the case? I thought it is content dependent.

Comment: It's variable - user can force a constant interval or let encoder decide with some soft constraints like max and min interval.